# Visa to Romania for Turkish passport holder

Tags: visas, visas-on-arrival, romania, turkish-citizens

I have a Turkish passport. Can I get a visa upon arrival at the airport in  Romania, or do I need to apply in advance at their Consulate?

If I need to apply in advance, can I apply in Abu Dhabi even though I don't have UAE residency? I have the Oman residency at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Romania Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://mae.ro/en/node/2040), Turkish passport holders do need a visa, issued in advance, not on arrival. Without it, you wouldn't be allowed to board a flight to the country, either from UAE or Oman. However, you should be able to apply online, using the [eVisa tool](https://evisa.mae.ro/Home?lang=en-US#). As there is not an embassy or consulate in Oman, you are also able to apply from a nearby country.

Romania Embassy in Abu Dhabi
2nd Str., Nr.9, W(14/1) plot No.13 at Al Rodha Area
PO Box 70416
Abu Dhabi
United Arab Emirates
Phone +971-244-59919
Fax +971-244-61143
Email romaniae@emirates.net.ae

Romania Embassy in Riyadh
Riyadh, King Fahad Quarter, Amin Al Rehany Street, Villa no.8
PO Box: 94319
Riyadh
Saudi Arabia
Phone +966-1-263-0456
Fax +966-1-456-9985
Emails:
 office@embrom.org.sa 
 embromriyadh@nesma.net.sa